# Convert XLS file to TXT with desired spaces

Tags: xls

I want to convert XLS file to a TXT file with desired spaces. I have an xls file with a large number of rows and a few number of columns.

Here is a sample file I need as the output file after converting XLS to TXT

```
CTR390706OOLU111491518.592210F      SIN  NSAITOCL N      CNT OOLCSD3430                  1
CTR131382OOLU115708004.972210F4.2   SIN  NSAITOCL N      NCC OOLCYG9882                  1
CTR260482OOLU616079109.194410F      H8M  NSAITOCL Y+14C  CON OOLDCW4756                  1
```

Comment: BELOW IS THE COLUMN WIDTH I REQUIRED.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to convert anything.
Just copy-paste the selected desired content into a text file and save it.
The spacing will be maintained if content words do not exceed the column size.
Alternately, you can just **save as** Unicode Text directly from Excel.